# Activating Show Details for Grand Total of Pivot Table in C#

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, office-interop

I'm trying to automate the creation of "Show Detail" of a Pivot Table from Excel using C#

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

My code:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\path_to_excel_file.xlsm");
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Sheet_Name"];

Excel.PivotTable pivot = worksheet.PivotTables("defined_pivot_table_name");
pivot.DataBodyRange.ShowDetail = true;
```

The code works, but it displays only the details of the first "Total" value. But what I want is to get the "Show Details" of the "Grand Total".
In this case for this pivot table, it will create a new sheet with the 4 elements, but what I want is for the Grand Total (202).

[image]

I've tried selecting it first by `pivot.PivotSelect("Grand Total");` but still no results. I've also checked `pivot.RowGrand` and `pivot.ColumnGrand` which both return True.

Comment: I do not know c#, but in VBA you would need to locate first the last cell that contains grand totals (in your image, cell that contains value `202`) and then with command `Range("B16").ShowDetails=True` it would work (if `202` it's in cell `B16`, of course). You need to locate the range and set to true property `ShowDetails`. Hope at least this can give you a clue. I can't post it as answer because is not `c#`. Check https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.showdetail . I post this because I've seen many codes in C# that uses a similar syntax to VBA when using Excel Objects.

Comment: If both `pivot.RowGrand` and `pivot.ColumnGrand` are true, then your pivottable has a grand total and you can use the last cell of its `TableRange1` for `Range.ShowDetail`.

Comment: @Asger this worked well. Thank you. Please expand your comment into an answer so I can award you the bounty :) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pivottable has both, `RowGrand` AND `ColumnGrand`, then it also has a grand total

```
if (pivot.RowGrand && pivot.ColumnGrand)
```

Then you can use the last cell of the pivottable's `TableRange1` to generate the details by `ShowDetail`

```
int countRows = pivot.TableRange1.Rows.Count;
int countColumns = pivot.TableRange1.Columns.Count;
pivot.TableRange1.Cells[countRows, countColumns].ShowDetail = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/winforms-spreadsheet-pivot-table-api-t298650) can help

```
// Access the pivot table by its name in the collection. 
PivotTable pivotTable = worksheet.PivotTables["PivotTable1"];


// Access the pivot field by its name in the collection. 
PivotField field = pivotTable.Fields["Category"];


// Display multiple subtotals for the field.   
field.SetSubtotal(PivotSubtotalFunctions.Sum | PivotSubtotalFunctions.Average);

// Show all subtotals at the bottom of each group. 
pivotTable.Layout.ShowAllSubtotals(false);

// Hide grand totals for rows.
pivotTable.Layout.ShowRowGrandTotals = False

// Hide grand totals for columns.
pivotTable.Layout.ShowColumnGrandTotals = False

// custom label for grand totals
pivotTable.View.GrandTotalCaption = "Total Sales";
```